# Editing different items on the same page with one form - Symfony2

Tags: symfony

I'm using Symfony2 and I have a list of items with a button to edit the item next to each of them. Something like this

Item 1 | *Edit*

Item 2 | *Edit*

Item 3 | *Edit*

On the same page is the form for edition, but it's hidden and when you click on a button to edit an item it becomes visible with js. The problem is that you're still on the same page and for each item the form should be populated with a different object. Do you have any idea how to achieve this, because when the url is not changing I don't know how to call different controller. Thank you very much in advance! :)

JS:

```
$(".editItem").on('click', function(){

    $(".show").toggle();
    return false;

});
```

Comment: When you say "becomes visible" are you talking about loading html from the server o filling a hidden form with the corresponding data ?

Comment: I mean that it's hidden with css, and when you click on the button, a js script makes it appear with an animation and you can see it already, but everything is on the frond end, the page stays the same, the form was there before clicking on the link, it was just invisible.

Comment: One form for all items or one form for each item ?

Comment: Can you add your javascript code please ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Many solutions :

- having only one controller and send him a hidden input with the Id of the element to edit ;
- having the corresponding action attribute set with javascript when you click the edit link.

If we use the first method, what we do is retrieving the current item with ajax or the form assuming that your edit's links look like that :

```
<a href="{{ path("url", {id: myid}) }}" data-id="{{ myid }}">Edit</a>
```

In javascript we do :

```
$('.editItem').click(function(e) {

   // We avoid the default behaviour (ie following the link)
   e.preventDefault();

   // We load the form with ajax
   $('.show').load('', {id: $(this).attr('data-id')});
});
```

And then in your controller (the one which displays the current view) :

```
 if($request->isXmlHttpRequest()) {
     $myid = $request->query->get('id'); // Could be $request->request


     $entity = $em->getRepository('...')->getOneById($myid);

     return $this->render('form.html.twig', array('entity' => $entity));

 }
```

Comment: Can you please give some more information for the first solution. My edit link are like this: `<a href="{{path('update_item', { 'id': item.Id })}}">Edit</a>` and I give the ID to the controller, but I don't want the whole page to change, just the information in the form which is displayed when you click.

Comment: Thank you very much! I keep trying this, but the problem is that if I click on the edit button of Item1, it will be populated in the form on the next opening of the form, not the current. For example now the form is populated with information about Item1 and I click to edit Item2 - when the form opens, it will be populated again with Item1, but the  next time I click whatever link for edition - the form will be poplulated with information about Item2 (the previous clicked link) Any ideas? :(

Comment: Take a look at jQuery.get and its "success" option (in which you append the data to your page). You can also debug using the developper console and looking for what is sent to your server in the network panel.

Comment: I think I found out a little more - it tooks time while the information for the new item is loaded from the database and during this time the form is still populated with the old content. When the new content is ready the form hides.

Answer (score 1):

Here's an approach I've used in the past:

- Create an entity which represents 'Item'
- Create a form type which allows you to edit 'Item' : http://symfony.com/doc/current/cookbook/form/create_custom_field_type.html
- In your form, define a Collection type, using the new type above: http://symfony.com/doc/current/reference/forms/types/collection.html
- define a custom theme for your type : http://symfony.com/doc/current/cookbook/form/form_customization.html

  - this custom theme will be used to generate wrapping html so that your JS can open / close appropriately.
  - if you call your new block after your new form type above (e.g. ItemType_widget) it'll be automatically picked up and used by form_widget(form). Note, you'll need to include your theme in twig template & your theme should extent Symfony's...
  - you'll can specify CSS class within that theme such that the sub forms are hidden.

Then, when you call your view, you can render the form and it'll automatically have sub-forms attached. Your JS then just needs to open / close the appropriate form.

when it comes to processing the form, you need will have them all so it's best if you have some method of identifying which element was just edited.

You'll also have troubles with labels - this is just a case of fiddling with the theme.